# How to make auto hyperlink regex ignore img tags with src?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex which replaces all plain-text hyperlinks into actual anchor tags.

```
$acturl = '~(?:(https?)://([^\s<]+)|(www\.[^\s<]+?\.[^\s<]+))(?<![\.,:])~i'; 

$content = preg_replace($acturl, '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $content);
```

However, the problem with this code is that it also converts img tags into anchors too.

For example,
`<img src="https://link.com">` will become `<img src="<a href='https://link.com'>https://link.com</a>">`.

Is there a way to have this regex ignore images and only operate on plain-text URLs?

Comment: What is the point of the negated lookbehind at the end of the pattern?  Your question could be improved by adding a battery of input strings and your exact expected result.  Your sample inputs are img tags, not plain text urls.

Comment: @Nick please remember to close mega-duplicate questions.  I was limited to 3 to close with, but there easily 10 pages that already answer this question.

Comment: @mickmackusa you are of course correct. Do you keep a list so you don't always have to search for them?

Comment: @Nick No I just google them using the wording in the question.  Then when I find a pile of solutions using the keywords that exist in the question, I don't feel like a jerk for hammering closed.  People are really taking offense to my hammering today.  Minus 10 on my account all in a row from no-comment downvotes on my questions.  Meh.

Comment: @mickmackusa that sucks. Something I have to look forward to I guess!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a negative look-behind to the beginning of your regex:

```
(?<!src=["'])
```

which will prevent a URL matching if it is preceded by the characters `src="` or `src='`.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Zlgpg)

Note that if you used a parser (e.g. [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)) you could avoid this problem by only replacing links in the text nodes.

Comment: Would the code look like this? `$acturl = '~(?<!src=")(?:(https?)://([^\s<]+)|(www\.[^\s<]+?\.[^\s<]+))(?<![\.,:])~i';`

It seems to do the same thing.

Comment: @Osman sorry, meant to include the demo link (which I've added now), but yes, that would be the new code.

Comment: Thanks Nick, this seems to work - though is there a way to get it to work with single quotes too? Currently it only works for `<img src="` and not `<img src='`.

Comment: @Osman have just updated answer and demo for single quotes as well.